# How to copy  a database's table to another database's corresponding one using TSQLConnection/dbExpress?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, dbexpress

I'm using C++ Builder (or Delphi 2007 and XE2) using DBExpress.
I connected two databases one for firebird(my local hard disk) one for MySQL(on Web)
using TSQLConnection.
Then, my question is ...
how can i use(make) SQL statement(or anything) to copy one table in Firebird into another table in MySQL? 
any comment will be very appreciate.. thanks a lot in advance..

Answer (score 6):

You can't copy the content from Firebird table to an MySQL Table using a SQL statement. Another RDBMS has this functionality for example Sql Server has [`Linked Servers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) and MySQL has [FEDERATED engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html) (only works for MySQL Databases).

So I eee two options to handle this task:

1. Iterate over the Datasets using a [`SqlExpr.TSQLQuery`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SqlExpr.TSQLQuery) or a [`SqlExpr.TSQLDataSet`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/SqlExpr.TSQLDataSet) and then Insert each record (row) manually in the MySQL Table.
2. Use a [TClientDataSet](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DBClient.TClientDataSet) to dump the Firebird table data using the [`SaveToFile`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.SaveToFile) method and then with another TClientDataSet load the Data using the [`LoadFromFile`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.LoadFromFile) method, finally you can [merge](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Merging_Changes_into_Data) the Data of the second TClientDataSet to the MySQL Table.